# How do I disable the administrators account?

Tags: password, users

My school gave me this Ubuntu laptop and it still has its schools administrators account on it. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Is this your laptop or something the school has lent to you?  Not so sure I feel comfortable with this as it is unclear if you have the rights to make the changes based on the way you've phrased the question

Comment: if he has the admin pwd he has permission  @JohnKirchner

Comment: @Rinzwind, good point.  Yet, he could have a password just to use the PC.  But, like you said, the sudo would do him no good without the admin password.  I was just being overly cautious.

Comment: @JohnKirchner never bad to be cautious but to me even physical access means owning the machine ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create your own user and make it an administrator. Remove the other administrator.  You can do all of this in the "user account" section (dash, "users"):

[image]

The + adds a new user. The - removes one.

I would advice to 1st make the new administrator and confirm it works as intended before you remove the original one.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo userdel --remove administrator
```

Replace `administrator` with the username of the admin account.

Less drastically, you could just lock the account:

```
sudo --expiredate 2013-11-27
```